# How to clear all pinned program items from the jump list

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar

I'm not able to **unpin** items of the *Windows Explorer*. When I click the pin icon the items becomes yellow/orange and nothing happens.

Is there an **Unpin all** command or a registry key where Explorer stores its pinned items?

Comment: Related: [How to clear jump lists for a specific program](https://superuser.com/q/616080/358766)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this article : ["How to Disable/Clear Recent MRU Items from Jump List of Windows 7"](http://www.blogsdna.com/2324/how-to-disableclear-recent-mru-items-from-jump-list-of-windows-7.htm):

> You can pin/unpin any program from
>   jump list menu but not possible to
>   remove recent list or Most Recently
>   Used. Here is small guide on how to
>   disable or clear recent list from
>   taskbar jump list in windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

**Here are a few articles you could try:**

- Unpinning jump-list items that "stick" and won't go away:  http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/LarryLarsen/How-to-Delete-Jump-List-Items
- Here's another related one that you could try:  http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/214711-taskbar-pinned-items-reset-clear-windows-7-a.html
- And yet another on jump-list items:  http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/81483-jump-lists-reset-clear-all-items.html