# How to clear jump lists for a specific program

Tags: windows, taskbar, jumplist

How do you clear the jump list of recently opened files for a specific program?

I'm looking to clear entries for programs on the Start Menu and pinned to the taskbar.

[image: Jump list]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Jump lists are stored in the user profile. To view them, open the following path:

`%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations`

Each file in there is a jump list for a single application. To find out the one you need, add or remove an item on the jump list you want to clear. Then sort the files in this folder by modified time to find out which one you just edited. Delete the file to remove the jump list.

In Windows 10, it is not possible to navigate to this path using Windows Explorer, however copying and pasting it to the address bar does work.

Comment: You can also search 'shell:recent' in start menu to open the current user \Recent\ folder.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [a comment](https://superuser.com/a/616309/45163#comment1388728_616309) on [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/616309/45163), you can enter `shell:recent` in an Explorer window to open the list of Recent Items. This list contains (Windows) links; just delete a link in this view to remove it from all Jump Lists.